# How to export SharePoint list data to excel using a timer job with custom coding?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new to *SharePoint* programming.
Can anyone tell me how I can export list data to *Excel* using a timer job with some custom code?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Can you show some code even miserably failed?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link for creating timer jobs in sharepoint.
This article is contain the detailed process.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3801/custom-sharepoint-timer-job/

The below code will help you to export the list data.

```js
public void Export(List<int> ids)
{ 
    DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
    try 
    { 
        SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site; 
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web; 
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
        { 
            using (SPSite siteE = new SPSite(site.ID)) 
             { 
                using (SPWeb webE = siteE.OpenWeb(web.ID)) 
                { 
                    webE.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; 
                    SPList list = webE.Lists["Stationery"]; 
                    table.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string)); 
                    table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Decimal)); 
                    DataRow newRow; 
                    GridView gv = new GridView(); 
                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items) 
                    { 
                        if (ids.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"].ToString())) && (item["Status"].ToString() == "New")) 
                        { 
                             newRow = table.Rows.Add(); 
                             newRow["Product"] = item["Product"].ToString(); 
                             newRow["Quantity"] = Convert.ToDecimal(item["Quantity"].ToString()); 
                             item["Status"] = "Exported"; 
                             item.Update(); 
                        } 
                     } 
                     SPBoundField boundField = new SPBoundField(); 
                     boundField.HeaderText = "Product"; 
                     boundField.DataField = "Product"; 
                     gv.Columns.Add(boundField); 
                     boundField = new SPBoundField(); 
                     boundField.HeaderText = "Quantity"; 
                     boundField.DataField = "Quantity"; 
                     boundField.ControlStyle.Width = new Unit(120); 
                     gv.Columns.Add(boundField); 
                     gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false; 
                     gv.DataSource = table.DefaultView; 
                     gv.DataBind(); 
                     gv.AllowSorting = false; 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent(); 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders(); 
                     string attachment = "attachment; filename=export" + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ".xls"; 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment); 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/Excel"; 
                     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
                     HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 
                     gv.RenderControl(htw); 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString()); 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.Close(); 
                     HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); 
                     webE.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false; 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.ToString()); 
     }
```